# provision a webpart

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

how do you provision a webpart in sharepoint?

Comment: I answered your question as best as I could but let me know if you would like me to tell you more. Your question was a little too unprecise to give a good answer.

Comment: yes i've exported a .webpart file.
what are the steps needed to provision this. i.e within the 12 hive what files are needed? i think i should be using the "alluserdata" webpart

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would like to provision a .webpart file. You do that through a <module> element in a feature. 
Then you add your webpart dll to the BIN folder through a wsp solution manifest and the last thing not to forget is to register the webpart a a safecontrol.
Using wsp builder will make this process much smoother.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008069/deploy-webpart-with-feature/1009544#1009544