# deploy webpart with feature

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How do you deploy a webpart within a feature?

i have my webpart as MyWebPart.cs file.

ive got got a feature which is used for something else. im just wondering if i can deploy this webpart along with the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to use a tool such as [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder). This integrates with Visual Studio and allows you to create a new web part with feature.

Try this out and incorporate the existing code and feature you've already written. I guarantee it will save you a lot of time compared to doing everything manually.

[VSeWSS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=B2C0B628-5CAB-48C1-8CAE-C34C1CCBDC0A) may also do the job but I've never found it as easy to use.

Comment: Agreed, WSPBuilder is absolutely the easiest way to build .wsp's.

Comment: Im deploying the feature with wspbuilder, but what i want to know is if i need to do anything else (do i need other files)? or is it just a matter of having a single webpart class

Answer (score 3):

So I guess you need help with deploying a webpart through a feature. Here´s how to do that.

In your elements.xml file (in the feature) add a module, like:

```
<Elements  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Module Name="WebParts" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp" Path="DWP">
    <File Url="MyWebpart.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Group" Value="MyWebPartGroup"></Property>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

The ***Path*** (DWP) is a folder in the feature where the actual .webpart file is stored and it can look like this:

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Full class name, Full 4-part assembly name" />
      <importErrorMessage>Import error message</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">My webpart</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Description of WP</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Using wsp builder to package this into a wsp makes things with safecontrols and DLL deployment etc so much easier so use that...